# Linear combination in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

$v_1,v_2,...v_k,b$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^n$
assume b is not the zero vector.
$b$ is a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$.

prove that if the set $\{v_1,v_2,...v_{k-1},b\}$ is linear independent then $v_k$ is a liner combination of the vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{k-1},b$.

I'm trying to somehow get to $s_1v_1 + s_2v_2 + \dots+s_{k-1}v_{k-1},s_b b = v_k$
But not sure how to get there with the givens.

Will appreciate your help

cheers

Comment: try fixing your text with mathjax. Like \$\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}\$ to get $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$. It will make it so much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Rephrasing the claimed statement isn't really "trying". Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I formatted your text, but in the future, you will find that many users refuse to answer questions that are written to be so unreadable. Please try to format with mathjax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write down exactly what you are given:

there exist scalars so that $a_1v_1+\dots a_kv_k=b$.

In particular,  $\frac{a_1v_1+\dots a_{k-1}v_k-b}{a_k}=v_k$

granted that $a_k \neq 0$.

What would be true if $a_k$ were zero?

Comment: not sure why we can assume that ak is not equal to zero.

Comment: I haven't used all of the assumptions in the problem...

Comment: Also not sure we are we using the given that {v1,v2,...vk−1,b} is linear independent.

Comment: we should be using that. Think about what it would mean for $a_k=0$.

Comment: Is that why we can divide by ak ? not sure I see the connection

Comment: write down the equation with $a_k=0$, and then think about what it means for $\{v_1, \dots,v_{k-1},b\}$ to be independent. I don't want to rob you of the insight this problem may give you.

Comment: it would mean that the set including the ak is linear dependent but the given excludes ak. it goes up to ak-1

Comment: That would mean that b is a linear combination of v1....vk-1. in that case the set v1....vk-1,b is linear dependent because one of the vectors(b) is a combinations of the others. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes :) nice one.

Answer (score 0):

If $b\in span\{v_1,v_2\cdots v_n\}$ then: $b=A_1v_1+A_2v_2+\cdots+A_nv_n$, move things a little and you get:$$b=A_1v_1+A_2v_2+\cdots+A_nv_n\\-A_nv_n=A_1v_1+A_2v_2+\cdots+A_{n-1}v_{n-1}+b\\ v_n=\frac{A_1}{-A_n}v_1+\frac{A_2}{-A_n}v_2+\cdots+\frac{A_{n-1}}{-A_n}v_{n-1}+\frac{1}{-A_n}b$$ now call $\frac{A_i}{-A_n}=B_i, B_n=\frac{1}{-A_n}$ and you have:$$v_n=B_1v_1+B_2v_2+\cdots+B_nb$$

Comment: not getting though why we assume that An is not equal to zero, I take it that you deduce it from one of the givens?

Comment: Also not sure were are we using the given that  {v1,v2,...vk−1,b} is linear independent.